# Dynamic OBB Collision Detection (Separating Axis Theorem): Find the Time That Collision Occurred?

Tags: java, collision-detection

Right now, I am trying use the separating axis theorem to implement a dynamic 3-D OBB collision test in Java. I'm trying to find the time from 0 to 1 of intersection for the entities for each separating axis, with 0 being the beginning of the frame and 1 being the end of the frame.

Here is my code:

```
private float calculateITime(OBB obb, 
Vector3f axis /*the separating axis we are testing*/,
Vector3f d /*Current OBB's origin minus other OBB's origin*/, 
float ra /*the first obb's projection*/,
float rb /*the second obb's projection*/,
float r /*what I understand to be the total length of the combined projections*/) {
    //Find the time, from 0 (the beginning of the frame) to 1 (the end of the frame), that the obb's first intersected.
    float intersectionLength = r - Math.abs(ra) - Math.abs(rb); //The measure of how much the two projections overlap

    Vector3f aVelocity = this.getCollisionPacket().getVelocity();
    Vector3f bVelocity = obb.getCollisionPacket().getVelocity();

    double aMagnitude = Mathematics.dotProduct(axis, Mathematics.crossProduct(aVelocity, d));
    double bMagnitude = Mathematics.dotProduct(axis, Mathematics.crossProduct(bVelocity, d));

    double totalDistanceCovered = 0;

    if(aMagnitude <= 0 && bMagnitude <= 0) {
        totalDistanceCovered = Math.abs(aMagnitude - bMagnitude);
    } else if((aMagnitude >= 0 && bMagnitude <= 0) || (aMagnitude <= 0 && bMagnitude >= 0)) {
        totalDistanceCovered = Math.abs(aMagnitude + bMagnitude);
    } else if(aMagnitude >= 0 && bMagnitude >= 0) {
        totalDistanceCovered = Math.abs(aMagnitude - bMagnitude);
    }

    System.out.println("PotentialITime: " + Math.abs(intersectionLength / totalDistanceCovered));
    return (float) Math.abs(intersectionLength / totalDistanceCovered);
}
```

However, I'm getting values way above one. Where am I going wrong, assuming that I'm even properly understanding how to properly implement the separating-axis theorem?

If you think you have an answer but it would be helpful if I posted the rest of the class (although it's pretty long), let me know and I'll do it for you. Thanks!

Final Notes:

This function is in the OBB class. As such, "this" refers to the OBB, and "obb" refers to the other OBB.

collisionPacket.getVelocity() returns the total displacement that will occur in a single frame should there be no collision.

"Mathematics" is my own static class. Assume it works properly. I didn't realize Vector3f had all those useful functions until after I made it.

[This](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DynamicCollisionDetection.pdf) is the PDF I'm using. I'm getting stuck at page 9, at 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few weeks later, I figured out how to do what I was trying to do. I actually came up with this a couple weeks ago, but I just now thought to post my solution.

```
private boolean determineCollision(OBB obb, Vector3f separatingAxis, double velocityMagnitude, float ra, float rb, float r) {
    //Find the time, from 0 (the beginning of the frame) to 1 (the end of the frame), that the obb's first intersected.

    //If r is negative, the first OBB is to the "right." Otherwise, it is to the "left."
    collisionRightSide.add(r < 0);
    boolean currColRightSide = collisionRightSide.get(collisionRightSide.size() - 1);

    double timeRange[] = new double[2]; //From 0 (beginning of frame) to 1 (end of frame)

    //Perform a regular static test if there is no movement for optimization's sake
    boolean noStaticOverlap = Math.abs(r) > (ra + rb);
    if(velocityMagnitude == 0) {
        timeRange[0] = 0; timeRange[1] = 1;
        axisTimes.add(timeRange);
        return !noStaticOverlap;
    }

    double spaceBetweenProjections = Math.abs(r) - Math.abs(ra) - Math.abs(rb);

    //Note that if velocity magnitude is negative, the first OBB is moving "right," and the other way for positive.
    if(currColRightSide) {
        if(velocityMagnitude < 0) {
            if(noStaticOverlap) {
//                  System.out.println("(Right side) OBBs are moving away");
                return false;
            } else {
                timeRange[0] = 0;
                timeRange[1] = Math.abs(spaceBetweenProjections / velocityMagnitude);
            }
        } else if(velocityMagnitude > 0) {
            if(noStaticOverlap) {
                timeRange[0] = Math.abs(spaceBetweenProjections / velocityMagnitude);;
                timeRange[1] = Math.abs((spaceBetweenProjections + 2 * rb) / velocityMagnitude);
            } else {
                timeRange[0] = 0;
                timeRange[1] = Math.abs((spaceBetweenProjections + 2 * rb) / velocityMagnitude);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(velocityMagnitude > 0) {
            if(noStaticOverlap) {
//                  System.out.println("(Left side) OBBs are moving away");
                return false;
            } else {
                timeRange[0] = 0;
                timeRange[1] = Math.abs(spaceBetweenProjections / velocityMagnitude);
            }
        } else if(velocityMagnitude < 0) {
            if(noStaticOverlap) {
                timeRange[0] = Math.abs(spaceBetweenProjections / velocityMagnitude);
                timeRange[1] = Math.abs((spaceBetweenProjections + 2 * rb) / velocityMagnitude);
            } else {
                timeRange[0] = 0;
                timeRange[1] = Math.abs((spaceBetweenProjections + 2 * rb) / velocityMagnitude);
            }
        }
    }       

    //Clamp values
    if(timeRange[0] < 0) timeRange[0] = 0;
    if(timeRange[1] > 1) timeRange[1] = 1;

    //Switch so that the greater value comes last
    if(timeRange[0] > timeRange[1]) {
        double temp = timeRange[0];
        timeRange[0] = timeRange[1];
        timeRange[1] = temp;
    }

    if(timeRange[0] > 1 && timeRange[1] < 0) return false;

    axisTimes.add(timeRange);

    return true;
}
```

Thanks to StackOverflow for giving me the Tumbleweed badge for this question. If someone comes up with a better or more optimized way of doing this, please let me know. Thanks! :D